# Creating a React component library with Webpack and Typescript but WP keeps bundling React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am trying to make an external component library. I am using Webpack and TypeScript.
Compiles fine but when trying to use the library I get:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
>   function component. This could happen for one of the following
>   reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the
>   renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of
>   Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>   See /react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>   and fix this problem.

Which sounds like webpack bundled React rather than respecting it being a peer dependency. Upon inspecting the bundled file, I can see hints of React's source code.

How do I prevent React from being bundled?
Here's the repo of the library

https://github.com/alshdavid-sandbox/react-component-lib-problem

Right now my webpack config looks like:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.ts'),
    mode,
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        publicPath: '',
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs'   
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
    },
};
```

Comment: Do you need `react-dom` too? Ex. `react-redux` has both react and react-dom

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the following to my webpack config

```
externals: {      
    react: {          
        commonjs: "react",          
        commonjs2: "react",          
        amd: "React",          
        root: "React"      
    },      
    "react-dom": {          
        commonjs: "react-dom",          
        commonjs2: "react-dom",          
        amd: "ReactDOM",          
        root: "ReactDOM"      
    }  
}
```